# Show that $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit.

> If $R\neq 0$ such that each finitely generated $R$-module is free then $R$ is a field.

In my notes there is the following proof:

We need to show that $\forall a\neq 0, Ra=R$.

Let $Ra\neq R$.

The $R$-module $R/Ra$ is $\neq 0$ since $Ra<R$ and it is finitely generated since it is generated over $R$ by $1+Ra$.

So, it is free $R$-module.

From an other proposition we have that $Ra=0$, so $a=0$. Contradiction.

So, $R=Ra$.

$$$$

I haven't really understood that proof...

Why does it stand that $R/Ra$ is $\neq 0$ when $Ra<R$ and why is $R/Ra$ generated over $R$ by $1+Ra$ ?

Comment: If $Ra=R$ then $a$ has an inverse.

Comment: The "we assume" at the start should be "we need to show that", it seems to me.

Comment: That first "We assume" is odd.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it... @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: for understanding what they mean, can someone give an example of a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ module which is not free ?

Comment: @user1952009 Any finite abelian group...

Comment: $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is cyclic, but not free since it has torsion.

Comment: @user1952009 **Any** abelian group is a $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ module. In fact, I think most authors consider both terms to be exactly the same.

Comment: Any abelian group $G$  is a $\mathbf Z$-module, since you can define (in additive notation), $\;nx$ for any $x\in G$, and easily check it satisfies the axioms for a $\mathbf Z$-module.

Comment: @Bernard : Yes but it is not obvious why the definition are [as they are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Examples) . So why the $1$ dimensional torus isn't a $\mathbb{R}$ module ?

Comment: @user1952009 I find it odd that you insist in this even after the link that *you yourself* post says exactly what I wrote above : "The concept of a Z-module agrees with the notion of an abelian group. That is, every abelian group is a module over the ring of integers Z in a unique way."

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed, but if *you* post a link and that link says *exactly* what others told you then it looks like it is not "learning" the main goal in that case. That's all. Thank you.

Comment: What is the 1-dimensional torus, for you – $\mathbf R/\mathbf Z$?

Comment: $R$ is a commutative ring, and $I$ a non-zero ideal of $R$. The point is that $I$ can be seen as a $R$ module, and If $I \ne R$ then as a $R$-module it is not free. Finally, one need to prove that if $R$ is a field then $R$ modules are $R$ vector spaces so they are free $R$ modules (not e that the only ideals of a field are $\{0\}$ and $R$). The conclusion is that for any $a \in R$ : $I = a R$ is an ideal, and if $R$ is not a field then one of them is $\ne R$.

Comment: @Bernard : yes. I see it now : it is not a (left) $\mathbb{R}$ module because $ \frac{1}{2} = 1.\frac{1}{2} =  (\frac{1}{2} . 2) . \frac{1}{2} \ne \frac{1}{2} . (2 .\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} . 0$ (the rule 3 in [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) )

Comment: It's exactly that (and it's linked to the fact that $\mathbf Z$ is *not* an $\mathbf R$-subspace).

Answer (score 1):

How about another proof?  If $M$ is a free module over a commutative ring with identity $A$, then any two bases of $M$ have the same cardinality.  This is a general fact about commutative rings ("invariant basis number").  That cardinality is called the *rank* of $M$.

If $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of free $A$-modules, then you can show that $$\textrm{Rank } M' + \textrm{Rank } M'' = \textrm{Rank } M$$ One way to show this is to use the fact that free modules are projective, and an exact sequence of projective modules must split.

Now assume that all finitely generated modules over a commutative ring with identity $R$ are free.  Let $0 \neq a \in R$...

What I'm writing in this paragraph isn't actually necessary for the proof; it's just related to the questions you asked: Suppose the $R$-module $Ra$ is properly contained in the $R$-module $R$.  Then the $R$-module $R/Ra$ is not zero, because if $x$ is an element of $R$ which is not in $Ra$, then $x+Ra$ is not the zero element of $R/Ra$ (if it was, then $x+Ra = 0 + Ra$ implies $x \in Ra$).

...The modules $Ra, R/Ra$ are finitely generated: the $R$-module generated by $1+Ra$ is $R/Ra$, and the $R$-module generated by $a$ is $Ra$.  The second claim is clear, the first one I believe you asked why in your question: if $r + Ra$ is any element of $R/Ra$ (for $r \in R$), then $r + Ra = r \cdot (1+Ra)$.  This is what it means for $1+Ra$ to generate $R/Ra$.

Now the sequence $$0 \rightarrow Ra \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/Ra \rightarrow 0$$ is exact.  So the rank of $R$, which is $1$, is equal to the rank of $Ra$ plus the rank of $R/Ra$.  A free module over a commutative ring with identity is the zero module if its rank is zero; otherwise it has positive rank.  This forces one of the modules $Ra, R/Ra$ to be zero.  But $Ra$ is not the zero module.

So $R/Ra$ is the zero module.  This means that $R = Ra$.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'd like to improve this answer if possible.